# AngularJS: Modify Bootstrap Modal after loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use this pretty [image cropper](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?BEAlLLl9) in my AngularJS project. When I use it the "normal" way, that is on a plain page, everything works fine. The problem is that I want to put it on to the Bootstrap modal dialog.

In order to initialize the cropper, I am supposed to execute this snippet:

```
$(".cropper").cropper({
    aspectRatio : 1.618,
    done : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But it has to be executed **after** the DOM of the modal is loaded. So I have tried to run it like this:

```
$scope.onCropOpen = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl : 'cropModal.html',
        controller : CropModalInstanceCtrl
    });

    modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
        $(".cropper").cropper({
            aspectRatio : 1.618,
            done : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Unfortunately, the cropper still is not being initialized. I know that it should work after calling it when the modal is loaded, because I ran it manually from the browser console (with the modal dialog open) and then the cropper "magically" initialized.

Comment: resolve your cropper object in `$modal.open`, but it's not best solution, you should have some factory which will return cropper constructor, and inside `CropModalInstanceCtrl` you will initialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple directive that can show you the direction.
Instead of defining element with class ".cropper", create element "image-cropper" (since directive name is "imageCropper"):

```
<image-cropper></image-cropper>
```

This is a pretty general snippet that should work in similar way for any jquery plugin.

*Don't forget to change module name from "myApp", to the name of your application module...

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('imageCropper', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,

                compile: function (element, attrs) {
                    var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

                    var html = "<img></img>"; 
                    var newElem = $(html); 
                    newElem.attr("src", attrs.src);
                    element.replaceWith(newElem);

                    return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                        element.cropper({
                            aspectRatio : 1.618,
                            done : function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        });

                    };

                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: Wow! Many thanks, works like a charm! I have modified it a little:

`var html = "<img></img>";
var newElem = $(html);
newElem.attr("src", attrs.src);
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the jquery code inside CropModalInstanceCtrl function:

```
var CropModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

   $(".cropper").cropper({
      aspectRatio : 1.618,
      done : function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
   });

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. This code executes before even the modal is shown, so it has no effect on the DOM.

Comment: I have in mind some "dirty" solution. But better is to create a directive (thats the best practice for DOM manipulation). What do you prefer?

Comment: Directives are elegant. So if you could show me how to do it, I would be grateful.

Answer (score -1):

Vitali's solution is done the proper way and definitely should be used. But if someone still needs a brute method, this worked for me as well:

```
modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $(".cropper").cropper({
            aspectRatio : 1.0,
            done : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Generally, this type of solutions should be avoided because timeouts might be treacherous.